# Name/Value class that I can inherit?

Tags: .net, class, collections, dictionary

Is there a base class that I should inherit from that is just a basic name/value pair?

For example, I have several classes that only have two properties (name and value).  They all called something unique liked Field, Data, etc. and are all used for different things but the innards are all the same, two properties (name and value) and they have a related collection class that inherits from CollectionBase.  Is there something I can do so they all share the same code or inherit from the same base class so it's not so redundant?  They are also located in different protection levels of the assembly as well so I don't want to just use the same class for every scenario.

```
    Public Class Field

        Public Sub New()

        End Sub

        Private _name As String
        Public Property Name() As String
            Get
                Return _name
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _name = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _value As String
        Public Property Value() As String
            Get
                Return _value
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _value = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class


    Private NotInheritable Class FieldCollection
        Inherits CollectionBase

        Public Sub New()

        End Sub

        Public Sub Add(ByVal field As Field)
            List.Add(field)
        End Sub

        Public Sub Remove(ByVal index As Integer)
            If index > Count - 1 Or index < 0 Then
                Console.WriteLine("Can't remove this item")
            Else
                List.RemoveAt(index)
            End If
        End Sub

        Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal index As Integer) As Field
            Get
                Return CType(List.Item(index), Field)
            End Get
        End Property

    End Class

    Public Class Data

        Public Sub New()

        End Sub

        Private _name As String
        Public Property Name() As String
            Get
                Return _name
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _name = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _value As String
        Public Property Value() As String
            Get
                Return _value
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _value = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class


    Private NotInheritable Class DataCollection
        Inherits CollectionBase

        Public Sub New()

        End Sub

        Public Sub Add(ByVal data As Data)
            List.Add(data)
        End Sub

        Public Sub Remove(ByVal index As Integer)
            If index > Count - 1 Or index < 0 Then
                Console.WriteLine("Can't remove this item")
            Else
                List.RemoveAt(index)
            End If
        End Sub

        Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal index As Integer) As Data
            Get
                Return CType(List.Item(index), Data)
            End Get
        End Property

    End Class
```

etc...

**UPDATE**

[Here's a PasteBin of the code that I'm looking to streamline.](http://pastebin.com/CBdgKxGq)  Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx). This structure is used for example by .NET's [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class to store generic values against a specific key and by the sounds of it should suit your requirements as long as inheritance is not an issue.

If however you do want to use inheritance of any kind, then you can either use .NET4s [`Tuple<T1, T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) (Although this would result in `.Item1`, `.Item2`) or alternatively, if inheritance is really required / needed, use composition to wrap the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` into a custom object.

**Edit:** Seeing your example this looks like a good use case for a `Dictionary<string, string>`. Is there a specific reason why you do not want to use a Dictionary or any of the other build in collection clases which'd be quite suitable for this? You can always "protect" certain classes by declaring them or their methods internal, private, protected etc to avoid them leaking too deep down, or too far up, your object model.

Comment: This would seem adequate, but the OP states that he does not want to use the same class and `KeyValuePair` is a `struct` so inheritance is not an option.

Comment: I am trying to write a class that inherits Tuple<Enum,string> but I can't get it to work. It just tells me Tuple<System.Enum,string> does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments. Even though I wrote a constructor that takes 2 arguments, an Enum, and a string.

Comment: @Nick The error is not complaining about your inheriting class, but rather about Tuple. As Tuple does not have a 0 argument constructor you will have to call one of the available constructors yourself. E.g. public MyClass(Enum myEnum, string str) : base(myEnum, str) { }. Although I'm not sure why you're inheriting from Tuple instead of just using it or a struct.

Comment: @J.Kommer I'm not using a struct because classes can't inherit a struct. I might just use a tuple instead of inheriting tuple, but I'm not sure about that yet.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you looking for KeyValuePair, it is what it sounds like

Answer (score 0):

The first object that comes to mind is the [KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx#Y0); however, your `class` cannot derive from a struct. I believe you could inherit from [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx). But there is one caveat to that - the Tuple is basically immutable.

Also, I don't know why you would be writing your own class derived from `CollectionBase`. I don't see any gain from what you have given - I would recommend using `List<Of Field>` ...or `List<Of Data>`.

I did come up with this very basic solution:

```
Module Module1
    Private fieldCollection As New List(Of Field)

    Sub Main()
        Dim _field As Field = New Field()
        _field.Name = "Foo"
        _field.Value = "BarBaz"

        fieldCollection.Add(_field)

    End Sub

End Module

Public Class Field
    Inherits DataPair

End Class

Public MustInherit Class DataPair
    Private _name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _value As String
    Public Property Value() As String
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _value = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

you could even go more generic and use a `Tuple<T1,T2>` [MSDN docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A KeyValuePair is a structure and as such can't be inherited, but might be useful in place of classes that inherit a base class.  Otherwise, I don't believe there is such a class you can inherit.  You could however, create your own.